# How to take a long string, and create smaller strings that start &end with a specific sequence of characters

Tags: java, regex

In my program I have used jsoup to parse a url and produce an html document. The site I am getting data from is just a chunk of plaintext, however, and has no elements or other features. I need to look through this document, and create strings that begin and end with a certain pattern of characters. I've been Looking into Regex.

Currently, I think the best way of doing what i aim to accomplish is to convert the HTML document into a string. Each substring I am looking to create begins with "{"world":"" and ends with ""}" but the information between those chunks can change, and has a variable length.

I need to know how I can use regex to detect those strings and create the strings from them, or if there is a better method to accomplish what I am trying to do,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to split the string. If the parts you want are seperated by `}{"world":""`, then you can use something like that as the delimitter:

```
String string = "{\"world\":\"whatever\"}{\"world\":\"something\"}";
String[] parts = string.split("}{\"world\":");
String part1 = parts[0]; // {"world":"whatever"
String part2 = parts[1]; // "something"}
```

Then I guess you could cut out parts you don't want from each part using [String.replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-):

```
String part1Cut = part1.replace("{\"world\":", ""); // "whatever"
String part2Cut = part2.replace("}", ""); // "something"
```

I'm confident that there's a much cleaner way to do this (I don't have much experience with manipulating strings), but I just wanted to bring these methods to you in case you weren't aware of them.